# Letterboxed image with ImageMagick and AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, imagemagick, aws-lambda, image-resizing

I have a functional Lambda node.js script that does the resizing of images. I would like to add white space to get the images in square. How do I add the ImageMagick commands into this line of code?

```js
                    this.resize(width, height)
                        .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) {
                            if (err) {
                                next(err);
                            } else {
                                next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                            }
                        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't read all those parentheses that litter Javascript, but you probably want to set `Gravity` to `Center`, set a background colour and then set the `Extent` to the size of the containing square. So try looking up the highlighted terms wherever your documentation is.

Comment: Hello @MarkSetchell. I know I need to use gravity center background and extent (height, width) but I can not get the commands working with this line of code:   this.resize(width, height)
                        .toBuffer(imageType, function(err, buffer) 
when I combine them, it just creates white image with the size set in the extent command

Comment: Try `this.resize().repage().extent().toBuffer()` or similar.